# Can Emacs render family emojis? (Emoji ZWJ Sequences)

Tags: fonts, unicode

For example (explained on [Emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/families/)): ‍‍‍

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [emojify](https://github.com/iqbalansari/emacs-emojify) package.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have the Symbola font installed, it will make use of it to render emojis:

[image: Emacs screenshot with family emojis]

Comment: @m43cap Consider turning that comment into an answer as comments risk to get deleted at any time.

Comment: Have do so - thanks. And I have deleted my original comment.

Comment: I do have Symbola installed. As can be seen in your screenshot, the family members are rendered individually and *not* as a family emoji. What is missing is support for [Emoji ZWJ Sequences](https://emojipedia.org/emoji-zwj-sequences/).

Comment: I recommend specifying that in the question (as opposed to linking to a website), it's otherwise not clear. We cannot know how it's rendered for you and what rendering you expect.